# Android Places Api get detailed information by coordinates

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-geocoder, reverse-geocoding

I need to get detailed information about a location. I already use Geocoder and is method "getFromLocation" to get addresses for coordinates... However, this does not provide detailed information about the location. Just the address. 
I need at least the name of the shop or company this coordinates belong to or are nearby. Therefore, I already had a look at Places-Api but there seems not to be a method where I can pass coordinates…

Comment: Places API nearby search accepts location and radius parameters to search places close to some coordinate. https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Answer (score 0):

Thank you xomena (comment above).

This is the url for the request:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=47.0619334,15.0901258&radius=500&key=asdaf